# line segments with edges into a curve

Tags: edges, bezier-curves

I want to give these line segments a continuous cylinder shape, like a Spaghetti noodle. My aim is to make this path visible in render mode. At the moment you are not able to see it in render mode because it has zero thickness.

I already converted them into a Bezier curve and played around with the Bezier Circle. The result were a lot of cylinders behind each other with a lot of gaps between them because the whole line has edges as you can see on the picture.

I also tried to solve the problem with a Skin-Modifier, but this didn't give me a good solution either. Maybe I should combine it with another Modifier.

So I was wondering if it's even possible to convert an 3D edged path into a curve path with a cylinder shape.

I would be very glad if someone could tell me how I get a good solution.

Thank you very much!

[image: Path contains straight line segments]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not that your path shape is composed of many segments, but that it is composed of many **separate objects**.

You should join them into one object before adding thickness to your curve, and you also have to join all overlapping vertex into a continuous spline. The modifiers you mention have no effect in what you want to achieve.

1. Select all your segment objects
2. Shift select on last segment to make it the active object
3. Join them all with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
4. Now enter edit mode on the newly created mesh object
5. Select all vertex
6. Press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*
7. Exit edit mode
8. Press  + <kbd>C</kbd> > *Convert to Curve*

You should now be able to successfully add thickness to your curve as a continuous path.

[image: Curve]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much @Duarte Farrajota Ramos

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right.

1. Make path, edit it as you need.
2. Make Bezier Circle.
3. Select Path and under Object data tab select Bezier Circle as Bevel Object.

Now you can resize Bezier Circle as you need.

[image: Path]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I don't want to make a path, I already have a path.

Comment: Is this was what you've needed?

Comment: I don't want to make a new path. I already have a given path as you can see in the picture. I just want the path looks continuous like yours in the picture. What I exactly did is: 1. Join all line segments 2. convert into curve 3. Add Bezier Circle 3. Select Circle as Bevel Object 4. resize. But I get gaps because my path is not a continuous curved.

Comment: Could you provide blend file with this path?

Comment: Sure! where/how can I provide the file?

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1730" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1730/)

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos was faster ;) If you want I've prepared for you (needs some details) version made of Bezier Curve. Easier to edit it.

http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1731/

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much Duarte Farrajota Ramos and doo0 !!

Comment: Can you maybe do me a favour and put in your steps? I got your blender file but I dont understand why your object is more curved than the one Duarte created. Thank you very much! @LukeD

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos just remove all overlaping vertices to make them connected. I've made this wire from scratch using 'bezier circle' and your lines as blueprint. If you need I can make a gif for you how to do this.

Comment: A gif would be very helpful!

Comment: Ok, here it is: 

1. Add 'Bezier Curve'.
2. Position it.
3. Go to 'Edit mode'.
4. Shorten the handles by selecting bezier point > S.
5. Position point, set handle.
6. 'E' to extrude.
7. Repeat.

[Gif steps](http://recordit.co/qXhatC6dUr)