# How can I add thickness to a polygonal chain?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm really new to blender and I'm trying to add thickness to a fairly complex polygonal chain. I've seen a lot on how to do it with Bezier curves but nothing on how to do it with polygonal chains. Does anybody know how to?

That orange dot in the middle is what I'm talking about the big mess on the left is my polygonal chain getting sucked towards it:

[image: chain image]

UPDATE: My problem was fixed thanks to this question and answer - [line segments with edges into a curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60716/line-segments-with-edges-into-a-curve)

Answer (score 7):

In *Edit Mode* select the whole mesh <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to ["**Shrink or Fatten**"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shrink-fatten.html?highlight=fatten) the mesh by dragging the cursor.

[image]

Comment: thank you but for some reason my pivot point is off to the side somewhere so when I do that it just moves away from that dot

Comment: Have you tried to change the pivot point type?

Comment: yes, same result. I will put a picture in the question to show what I mean

Comment: Oh I see now, when I said polygonal chain I meant chain of line segments that make up a curve not an actual chain made of polygons, sorry for not making that clear

Comment: Cool GIF, another useful tool I totally overlooked.