# Vertices in a line will not select in loop

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am trying to select all vertices in a line and would like to assign them to an edge loop or some sort of group so they can be selected all at once. When I do select them manually the orange selection color does not cover the entire line, but fades out between vertices. I included a plane width edge loops for reference in the image.  Limited dissolve will not work on vertices once they are selected like this.

Any ideas what I am missing?

[image: Vertices in line will not select, plane in bottom right as example]

Comment: Did you check for doubles?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60716/line-segments-with-edges-into-a-curve/